# dereference a variable in a struct from a list in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to dereference variables in a struct that is in a list, so here is my list and struct

```
struct packet {
 unsigned short block_num;
 unsigned short block_size;
 unsigned short crc;
 unsigned char  *payload;
}packet;
```

/* Function and type declaration for list of packets */

```
typedef struct List{
    struct packet *p;
    struct List *next;
}List;
```

And here I am trying to do a toString():

```
char *tostring(List *h) {
 char *str= malloc(STRSIZE);
 char num[sizeof(List)*100];
 str[0] = '\0';
 while (h != NULL) {
     sprintf(num, "package Number: %d \n", h->p->block_num);
     sprintf(num, "block size: %d \n", h->p->block_size);
     sprintf(num, "CRC: %d", h->p->crc);
     strncat(str, num, STRSIZE - strlen(str) - 1);
     h = h->next;
 }
 return str;
}
```

And I hit a segmentation fault, please help, thanks !

So, in C#, I will use list.ElementAt(i).block_num , how is it done in C ?

edit: new ones, the problem lies on my dereferencing

```
char *tostring(List *h) {
 char *str= malloc(STRSIZE);
 printf("line1");
 char num[sizeof(List)*100];
 char size[sizeof(List)*100];
 char crcs[sizeof(List)*100];
 char messages[sizeof(List)*100];
while (h != NULL) {
    sprintf(num, "package Number: %d \n", h->p->block_num);      
    sprintf(size, "block size: %d \n", h->p->block_size);       
    sprintf(crcs, "CRC: %d", h->p->crc);
    sprintf(messages, "CRC: %s", h->p->payload);
    strncat(str,num,sizeof(num));
    strncat(str,size,sizeof(size));
    strncat(str,crcs,sizeof(crcs));
    strncat(str,messages,strlen(num));
    h = h->next;

}
return str;
}
```

Comment: I would start by suggesting that char num[sizeof(*h)] is not big enough to hold the string "package Number: xxxxx\n".

Comment: Increase the size of the `num` array, and use a strcpy after _every_ `sprintf`. Also remember that the str will be a really large string depending upon the size of your list. Just curious, why do you need to put everything into memory as a string?

Comment: It is an assignment, we have to packetize a txt file, put them in a linked list, and print out the linked list

Comment: Did you try to debug the program?

Comment: I tried , but nothing came out, it just tells me that it gives a sementation fault, and I have no idea how to retrieve values inside. in C#, it is list.ElementAt(i).block_num, but how is it being carried out in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `sizeof(*h)` to determine the number of `List` elements in an array?

`sizeof(*h)` returns the size of `List`. Since `tostring()` only get's a pointer to a `List`, it has no way of knowing how many elements are pointed to.

In any case, it appears you are then writing a string to a character array of this size. What does the size of `List` have to do with the number of elements in the array? What are you trying to do?

Comment: This answer is really a comment, since it doesn't suggest a solution.

Comment: I sincerely don't know what to put for the size of the array, I am too used to used LinkedList in C#, now everything in C is just extra difficult for me.

Comment: @NebulaSleuth: Glad you've started using stackoverflow. However, the question seemed to me to be about why he was getting a segmentation fault. It was that question that I was trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that may go wrong here

1. Your SRTSIZE may be low to hold all the text that you start appending to str. For that you can start with a big buffer for now to eliminiate that.
2. As posted from previous answers you are always overwriting num. You should write to 'str' after you  create num every time
3. strncat implementation seems incorrect. You should use strlen(num).

   strncat(str, num, strlen(num));

char * strncat ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
The final parameter expects 
    Maximum number of characters to be appended.

refer : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/